# GetManifestResourceStream Returning Different Versions of Embedded XML File

Tags: c#, .net, dll, embedded-resource

## Background

Coded UI Test Case is accessing an XML configuration file embedded in a DLL created by the development team.  The test case verifies the UI is displaying the same configuration values provided in the XML file.  (The UI is supposed to be loading configuration from this XML file).

The test case gains access to the XML file as follows:

```
Assembly assemblyWithResource = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile: @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Install Location\DevCreated.dll");
Stream stream = assemblyWithResource.GetManifestResourceStream(name: ConfigFileName.xml);
```

When the test case executes, the stream returned from the GetManifestResourceStream call is not correct. The test case fails because the UI value does not match the XML config value.  The UI is showing what is in the current version of the XML file (correct).  The stream returned from the executing code is from an older version of the XML file (wrong).

This is one of the first test cases written while hammering out architecture/framework plans so it had been executing without issue for over a year.

## Debug

### Reproducibility

Only able to reproduce the problem by running the test case through MTM on the test VM environment.  Unable to reproduce running the test case on my personal computer, running the test case through MTM on another configured test VM or my usual go-to for trial/error deubg - ripping the guts of a test case into a console app.  I like to do that so I don't have to mess with the overhead of checking in code and deploying (and can easily pass code back to the dev team without them having to deal with it either).

Running the code where the test case is getting the XML file from the DLL (two lines shown above) in a plain old console app on the same test VM where the original test case fails returns the correct XML file contents.

### Differences in Deployed Test Case Code vs Console App Code

Initially focused on what was different between the MTM executed test case and the console app because they could be run on the same VM.  Looked at the following information for the Assembly:

- Location, CodeBase, HostContext, GlobalAssemblyCache, PermissionSet
- Dumped the array from GetManifestResourceNames and the ResourceLocation for the ManifestResourceInfo

None of the assembly attributes that were looked at were different. It looks as if the test case code and console app code are loading the same DLL from the same location and accessing the same embedded file name but obtaining different versions of the file.

Spent time digging in TFS and did find the version of dev code that contains the same XML file that the MTM executed test case is loading - it's about 6 weeks old.  It was changed 3 weeks ago and has been failing ever since.  This established a time period based on changesets.

There are no other XML files embedded in this DLL to look at.  XML files embedded in other DLLs that have seen changes during the same time period appear to be loading correctly.

The DLL is not located in the GAC, all other DLLs not part of the installed version were removed from the VM.

On the dev side the XML file is setup with a Build Action of Embedded Resource, does not copy to the output directory.

I've done a nominal amount of additional research to learn more about how the GetManifestResourceStream call works - it seems if there are any issues at all this will return a null Stream (not a different file) and how embedded files are included in an assembly.

## Questions

What to try next? I'm trying to narrow down a focus to continue digging:

- Is this an issue that stems from how the dev team has built this DLL?
- Is it an issue with how the DLL is included/packaged with the installer?  (Currently uninstalling and planning to copy/paste application and DLLs from the drop folder for the build to eliminate the installer.)
- Is it an environment issue on the VM where the test case is executing?
- Is it an issue with how the application is being deployed to the VM for testing?
- Is it an issue with how the test cases are deployed to the VM for testing? DLL hell?

The VM will be re-imaged soon, at which point I fear this problem is going to go away.  It's a pretty big concern of mine because we didn't realize the test case  was using the wrong version of an XML file.

## Update

In the process of trying to not use the installer any copy/paste the application and DLLs onto the test VM, something IIS related got messed up and I ended up re-doing most things IIS related on the VM.  Never did get the copy/paste to work (because of IIS/configuration stuff) so reinstalled the application and now I no longer see the test case fail.  What about IIS would have anything to do with embedded files in a DLL?